# what is the difference between '' and ' ' in read.table of R?

Tags: r

Here is my simple text (named test):

```
  name      sex     age  height  
1 x1        F       18   162
2 x2        M       19   170
3 x3        M       21   178
4 x4        F       22   166
5 x5        F       23   165

>read.table('test', sep='')
```

It's ok.

```
>read.table('test', sep=' ')  

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :   
  line 1 did not have 20 elements
```

I want to know why.

What is the difference between  '' and ' '  in read.table of R? Please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, the default value of `''` means "any amount of whitespace" whereas your second choice `' '` means *precisely one space* which is in fact very different.

The wording (in `help(read.table)`) is not ideal but gets the job done:

> ```
>  sep: the field separator character.  Values on each line of the
>       file are separated by this character.  If ‘sep = ""’ (the
>       default for ‘read.table’) the separator is ‘white space’,
>       that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage
>       returns.
> ```

You want the default value, unless you know you have, say, a comma-delimited csv file.